# mobile geth not connecting to peers

Tags: go-ethereum, peers, android

I want to have a mobile geth implementation on my android device and started with this code: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Mobile-Clients:-Libraries-and-Inproc-Ethereum-Nodes .

Then i configured the testnet like this:

```
NodeConfig nc = new NodeConfig();
nc.setEthereumNetworkID(3);
String genesis = Geth.testnetGenesis();
nc.setEthereumGenesis(genesis);
node = Geth.newNode(getFilesDir() + "/.ethereum", nc);
node.start();
```

At first, this worked fine and the blocks were synced, but 6 weeks ago it suddenly stopped working and in the android monitor displays:

```
Starting P2P networking 
Light client mode is an experimental feature 
started whisper v.5.0 
RLPx listener up self="enode://b97dcd39adedc6cedda20eae4d5827513fecb83c3744b2c499219845f89b4a8fe498b875b17ee4197702d0470cc1b33c5605bf1ccf998ce54fdf1150a8438324@[::]:38134?discport=0"
D/DisplayLatestBlock: Could not display the latest block: no suitable peers available
```

Does anybody have a solution for this problem?